# AWS SAM passing path parameters to state machine triggered by api call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-sam

I am creating a state machine in SAM that is triggered by API Gateway.

```
  PartnerDownloadFileMachine:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::StateMachine'
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: statemachines/partner-download-file.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        CheckPartnerCredentialsArn: !GetAtt CheckPartnerCredentials.Arn
      Events:
        PartnerDownloadFileEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: get
            Path: /oauth2/DownloadFile/{partnerId}/{accessToken}/{fileId}
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: !Ref CheckPartnerCredentials
```

And first lambda definition in my state machine definition

```
"States": {
  "Check Partner Credentials": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "${CheckPartnerCredentialsArn}",
    "Next": "Valid Partner Credentials?"
  },
```

And the state machine is triggered by the api call but what I need is access to the path parameters in the api call but my lambda function cannot see them.  What do I need to do so that I have access to the path parameters?